# SCSS nested linked properties

Tags: sass

```
  td.dataTables_empty,
  th.dataTables_empty {
    // properties
  }
```

How to achieve the above CSS output in SCSS

I was trying with the following, but the output is different.

```
  th, td {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;

    &.dataTables_empty {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How much output was different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a term for such selector in css called selector lists. So, the nested rules for each complex selector lists in scss is nested separately, and then they are combined back together into a selector list (css).

```
th, td {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;

    &.dataTables_empty {
      text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Scss preprocessor compiler will compile your given scss into following css.

```
th, td {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

th.dataTables_empty, 
td.dataTables_empty {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, just remove the & if the HTML looks like that:

```html
<th>
    <div class="dataTables_empty"></div>
</th>
<td>
    <div class="dataTables_empty"></div>
</td>
```

```
  th, td {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;

    .dataTables_empty {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
```